# Upload and show with flask a dataframe | AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: dataframe, flask, replace, attributeerror

I am trying to upload and show a dataframe by flask and when I want to show it, it says

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'replace'.
```

I found this code on YT and I don't know if it is correct. Can somebody help me?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import pandas as pd
import csv

def reencode(file):
    for line in file:
       yield line.decode('windows-1250').encode('utf-8')

@app.route("/data")
def data():
  df = pd.read_csv("Sistema_de_Stock.csv", encoding='latin-1')
  df = df.drop(df.loc['stock al cargar':].columns, axis=1)
  df.to_html('data.html')
  with open("data.html", 'r', encoding='latin-1') as file:
    file = file.read
  **file = file.replace("<table","<table class='rwd-table'")**
  with open("data.html","w") as file_write:
    file_write.write(html + file)
  data = os.startfile("data.html")

  return data
```

Answer (score 0):

`file.read` is a *method*, so you should *call* the method. Furthermore you might want to rename the variable to make it clear that this is *not* a file handler:

```
with open('data.html', 'r', encoding='latin-1') as file:
    #    call the method ↓
    file_data = file.read().replace('<table', "<table class='rwd-table'")
  with open('data.html', 'w') as file_write:
    file_write.write(html + file_data)
  data = os.startfile('data.html')
```